# How to get date of another country using datetime?

Tags: python

How to get the date of another country in your country using datetime(we can use other packages)?

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use datetime and pytz module :

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
  
# get the standard UTC time 
UTC = pytz.utc
  
# it will get the time zone 
# of the specified location
IST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
  
# print the date and time in
# standard format
print("UTC in Default Format : ", 
      datetime.now(UTC))
  
print("IST in Default Format : ", 
      datetime.now(IST))
  
# print the date and time in 
# specified format
datetime_utc = datetime.now(UTC)
print("Date & Time in UTC : ",
      datetime_utc.strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S %Z %z'))
  
datetime_ist = datetime.now(IST)
print("Date & Time in IST : ", 
      datetime_ist.strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S %Z %z'))
```

Comment: This is a verbatim copy of https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-current-time-in-different-timezone-using-python/